# isc-dhcp for Virtual Machines only

Tags: networking, virtualization, dhcp, network-bridge, xen

I installed Xen 4.3 on Ubuntu Server 14.04 and added the xenbr0 bridge.

The host IP is 145.173.136.2.

The network administrator reserved 15 IP's for the VMs: 145.173.136.112-126

So i installed the isc-dhcp-server on the host with the above ip range and the interface to listen "xenbr0". With this settup the VMs get there ip address. But also other physical computers in the network gets an ip address from this range.

Is there a solution for the dhcp server to only give ip's to the VMs and not outside the server?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a netmask in dhcp.conf so your dhcp server only "answers" when requests from the special subnet come in.

> Declarations about network topology include the shared-network and the subnet declarations
>   [Source](http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.conf)